# Retrieving the value of the cell in the same row in the specific column using VBA

Tags: excel, vba, loops, while-loop

I'm currently working on the statement that implies, that if any of the cell value in the range of "G3:ED3" in the worksheet named "Matrix", matches the cell value in the range of "H3:H204" in the worksheet named "Staff" and any cell value in the range "G5:ED57" in the "Matrix" worksheet is numeric, then the value of the cell in a column B, that intersects the numeric value, is retrieving to the required cell address in the target template.

Here's what I have tried so far:

```
    Dim rng1 As Range
    Set rng1 = Worksheets("Matrix").Range("G3:ED3")
    Dim rng2 As Range
    Set rng2 = Worksheets("Staff").Range("H3:H204")
    Dim rng3 As Range
    Set rng3 = Worksheets("Matrix").Range("G5:ED57")

    For Each cell In Range(rng1, rng2, rng3)
    While IsNumeric(rng3) And rng1.Value = rng2.Value
    Worksheets("Matrix").Columns("B").Find(0).Row = 
    Worksheets("TEMPLATE_TARGET").Value(12, 4)
    Wend
```

I'm unsure how to define the statement, so the code would automatically retrieve the value of the cell in a column B, that intersects any cell that contains numeric value in the rng3. Any recommendations would be highly appreciated.

Comment: You might be mixing up cells and ranges here. Please make a list of all single steps you want to achieve with this part of your code and post them here (in order). Each line must be a single logical step.

Comment: The required algorithm looks like that: 1. Check if the cell value in rng1 matches the range rng2, which serves as identifier for a records of items, that begins with '0'(01MNG, 02APT,etc); 2. Transcript the value of number, indicated in a rng3; 3. Get the value of the cell in a column B, that is located in the same row as the indicated number; 4. Retrieve it in the worksheet named "TEMPLATE_TARGET"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's probably best you take a proper look into documentation / whatever learning resource you are using as you seem to have missunderstood how `While` works *(alongside few other things)*

`While` is a loop within itself, it does not act as an `Exit` Condition for the `For` loop.

---

With all that said, it's also unclear from your question what you're trying to achieve.

> My presumption is, that you want to check for all the conditions and
>   then if they do match, you're looking to paste the result into the
>   "`TEMPLATE`" sheet

First we create a function th ceck for values in the two data ranges:

```
Private Function IsInColumn(ByVal value As Variant, ByVal inSheet As String) As Boolean
Dim searchrange As Range

On Error Resume Next ' disables error checking (Subscript out of range if sheet not found)

    ' the range we search in
    If Trim(LCase(inSheet)) = "matrix" Then
        Set searchrange = Sheets("Matrix").Range("G5:ED7")
    ElseIf Trim(LCase(inSheet)) = "staff" Then
        Set searchrange = Sheets("Staff").Range("H3:H204")
    Else
        MsgBox ("Sheet: " & inSheet & " was not found")
        Exit Function
    End If

On Error GoTo 0 ' re-enable error checking

    Dim result As Range
    Set result = searchrange.Find(What:=value, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)
    ' Find returns the find to a Range called result

    If result Is Nothing Then
        IsInColumn = False ' if not found is search range, return false

    Else
        If IsNumeric(result) Then ' check for number
            IsInColumn = True ' ding ding ding, match was found
        Else
            IsInColumn = False ' if it's not a number
        End If
    End If

End Function
```

And then we run the procedure for our search.

```
Private Sub check_in_column()

    Dim looprange As Range: Set looprange = Sheets("Matrix").Range("G3:ED3")
    Dim last_row As Long

    For Each cell In looprange ' loops through all the cells in looprange
        'utlizes our created IsInColumn function
        If IsInColumn(cell.Value2, "Matrix") = True And _
           IsInColumn(cell.Value2, "Staff") = True Then
             ' finds last actively used row in TEMPLATE_TARGET
            last_row = Sheets("TEMPLATE_TARGET").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
            ' pastes the found value
            Sheets("TEMPLATE_TARGET").Cells(last_row, "A") = cell.Value2
        End If

    ' otherwise go to next cell
    Next cell

End Sub
```

---

I redefined your ranges a little in my example for utility reasons but it works as expected

In my `Matrix` sheet: *(staff sheet only contains copy of this table)*

[image]

In my `TEMPLATE_TARGET` sheet after running the procedure.

[image]

**Result as expected**

Answer (score 0):

If I understand well, I would have done something like this:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub Main()

    Dim wsMatrix As Worksheet: Set wsMatrix = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Matrix")
    Dim rgMatrix As Range: Set rgMatrix = wsMatrix.Range("G3:ED3")

    Dim cell As Range
    Dim cellStaff As Range
    Dim cellMatrix As Range

    For Each cell In rgMatrix
        If CheckRangeStaff(cell.Range) And CheckRangeMatrix() Then
             'Process in a column B? Which sheet? Which cell? Which Process?
        End If
    Next cell

    Debug.Print ("End program.")

End Sub

Public Function CheckRangeStaff(ByVal value As String) As Boolean

    Dim wsStaff As Worksheet: Set wsStaff = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Staff")
    Dim rgStaff As Range: Set rgStaff = wsStaff.Range("H3:H204")
    Dim res As Boolean
    Dim cell As Range

    res = False

    For Each cell In rgStaff
         If cell.value = value Then
             res = True
             Exit For
         End If
    Next cell

    CheckRangeStaff = res

End Function

Public Function CheckRangeMatrix() As Boolean

    Dim wsMatrix As Worksheet: Set wsMatrix = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Matrix")
    Dim rgMatrix As Range: Set rgMatrix = wsMatrix.Range("G5:ED57")
    Dim res As Boolean
    Dim cell As Range

    res = False

    For Each cell In rgMatrix
         If IsNumeric(cell.value) Then
             res = True
             Exit For
         End If
    Next cell

    CheckRangeMatrix = res

End Function
```